# Difference between usage of pointer to char and char array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, gcc, char

In the following code, fizz prints correctly, but buzz does not. What is wrong with using a char array here or in what way am I using it wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int i;

    char *fizz = "fizz";
    char buzz[4] = "buzz";

    for(i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            if(!((i %3 == 0) || (i%5 == 0)))
                    printf("%d", i);
            if(i%3 == 0)
                    printf("%s", fizz);
            if(i%5 == 0)
                    printf("%s", buzz);

            printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: this line: char buzz[4] = "buzz"; will overflow the buzz[] buffer because strings contain a nul termination byte, so "buzz" is actually 5 bytes long.  writing past the end of the buffer is undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event

Answer (score 6):

Neither string is actually four bytes long. C strings are *NUL-terminated*, so they're always their length in characters plus one for the `'\0'` character. Therefore, you should change the declaration of `buzz` as follows:

```
char buzz[5] = "buzz";
```

However, also note that explicitly declaring the variable's length when initializing with a string literal is not required. You can just leave out the number, and it will work fine.

```
char buzz[] = "buzz";
```

Answer (score 3):

The `%s` specifier prints a *string*. A string is a series of characters followed by a null-terminator. To put it another way, you tell `printf` where your characters start, and `printf` keeps printing until it encounters a null terminator.

The `"buzz"` expression is a null-terminated string, however you shoe-horned it into `char buzz[4]` so the null terminator didn't fit. The result is that the `buzz` array does not contain a null terminator, and so `printf` reads off the end of the string, causing undefined behaviour. To fix this write:

```
char buzz[] = "buzz";
```

which will include a null terminator and allocate the right amount of space.

Answer (score 3):

You have declared the size of the buzz array as 4 and including `\0` the size of the string is 5. so you have to change the size of the buzz array as 5 or don't mention the size.

```
char buzz[5] = "buzz";
```

because buzz is not a  pointer variable, if the buzz is a pointer variable it will allocate the memory according to the string, so there is no need to specify the size. 
As buzz is a array you have to mention the size correctly. 
And while printing we use `%s` , `%s` will print the string till the \0 character occurs.
In the buzz string there is no \0 character, this is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

buzz contains 4 character, it has no space reserved for the null character, therefore it cannot be printed correctly with %s. %s specifies that a null terminated string to be printed and it cannot work correctly if the string is not null terminated.

Change your initialization to `char buzz[] = "buzz"`